# Oracle ManagedDataAccess Client and closing connections

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0

I'm trying to use Oracle's Managed Data Access client (version 4.121.1.0) within an application. I have no problems making small queries to the database but I'm running into a problem with a query which returns a large result.

I'm selecting two columns (all rows) from a table with about 137,000 records. One column is a number (id) and the other is a big CLOB of text. I'm using a data reader to read all of the clob data, with the id,  into a list of objects. All of this works fine and takes about 10 minutes to get all of it (the clobs can be pretty big).

After populating the array I call the Close() method on the connection and wait, and wait, and wait... It takes about an hour and 25 minutes for the connection to close. Once the connection closes, the application continues to run normally. Why is it taking so long to close the connection?

Here's an example of my current code which exhibits the problem.

```
 List<StudentData> studentData = new List<StudentData>();
 using (OracleConnection connection = new     OracleConnection(this.ConnectionString))
 {
     try
     {
         // Get all the clobs
         OracleCommand cmdGetClobs = new OracleCommand("SELECT STUDENT_NUMBER, CUSTOM FROM PS.STUDENTS", connection);
         connection.Open();
         var rdr = cmdGetClobs.ExecuteReader();
         while (rdr.Read())
         {
             System.Char[] clobData = new System.Char[rdr.GetOracleClob(1).Length];
             rdr.GetChars(1, 0, clobData, 0, (int)rdr.GetOracleClob(1).Length);
             string studentNumber = rdr["STUDENT_NUMBER"].ToString().Trim();
             StudentData data = new StudentData()
             {
                 Student_Number = studentNumber,
                 ClobValue = clobData
             };
             studentData.Add(data);
         }
         // I've tried with, and without calling the dispose methods.
         rdr.Dispose();
         cmdGetClobs.Dispose();
         connection.Close();  // <--- App will hang here for about 1.5 hours
         connection.Dispose();
     }
     finally
     {
         if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
         {
             connection.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sigh... No one? An update...
I updated an existing, working, app which makes the same query using the old, un-managed, odp.net. I has the same issue using the managed code but works fine using the un-managed code.

Answer (score 1):

OracleClob implements IDisposable itself.  Depending on the number of students you have there will be a lot of Clobs to clean up.

Can you do something like this to see if it helps?

```
while (rdr.Read())
     {
         using (OracleClob clobData = rdr.GetOracleClob(1))
         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(clobData))
         {
            string studentNumber = rdr["STUDENT_NUMBER"].ToString().Trim();
            StudentData data = new StudentData()
            {
             Student_Number = studentNumber,
             ClobValue = reader.ReadToEnd()
            };
            studentData.Add(data);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Hmm.. Sounds like a plausible solution. It would make sense that the connection couldn't close until all the OracleClobs were closed. However I don't really have a way to test it any more. The giant clob field has been replaced with a different solution by the product vendor.